# Allow specific inline styles in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

I want to allow the inline style "border-collapse: collapse" when I'm pasting tables from Word but the code below is not working:

```
config.allowedContent = 'table{border-collapse}';
```

What am I missing here? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
config.extraAllowedContent = 'table{border-collapse}';
```

Comment: This is the correct solution for this, please mark it as answered so that it does not hang unanswered.